# Add animation to pie chart on page load nvd3 library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, pie-chart

Im using `angular`- `nvd3` chart library. sample I used [here](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/site.html) `PieCharts`.
Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/3g3bfemg/). I wand to add animation on load...and also animation of slices also not working properly. Any help will be greatly appreciated..

```
 var testdata2 = [
        {key: "REGISTER", y: 5},
        {key: "CONTINUE", y: 2},
        {key: "COMPLETE", y: 9}
    ];

var height = 350;
var width = 350;

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.key })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y })
        .width(width)
        .height(height)
        .showLabels(true)
        .labelThreshold(.05)  
        .labelType("percent");

    d3.select("#test1")
        .datum(testdata2)
        .transition().duration(1200)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .call(chart);


    return chart;
});`
```

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing now. Did you get a solution?